# SQLDatabase won't save string

Tags: android, sqlite, manifest

I am currently making a simple Android sql database program. The first activity works, but it doesn't save the text I input in the edit text. here is my code:

```
public class DatabaseFinalActivity extends Activity {
    NoteAdapter adapter=null;
    NoteHelper helper=null;
    Cursor dataset_cursor=null;
    EditText editNote=null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            editNote = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            helper=new NoteHelper(this);
            dataset_cursor=helper.getAll();
            startManagingCursor(dataset_cursor);
            adapter=new NoteAdapter(dataset_cursor);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btn.setOnClickListener(onSave); 
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", "Error in code: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        helper.close();
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            helper.insert(editNote.getText().toString());
            dataset_cursor.requery();
            editNote.setText("");
        }
    };

    class NoteAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
        NoteAdapter(Cursor c) {
            super(DatabaseFinalActivity.this, c);
        }

        @Override 
        public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c) 
        {
            NoteHolder holder=(NoteHolder)row.getTag();
            holder.populateFrom(c, helper);
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            NoteHolder holder=new NoteHolder(row);

            row.setTag(holder);
            return(row);
        }
    }

    static class NoteHolder {
        private TextView noteText=null;
        NoteHolder(View row){
            noteText=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        }

        void populateFrom(Cursor c, NoteHelper helper) {
            noteText.setText(helper.getNote(c)); 
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my helper:

```
public class NoteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="note.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION=1;

    public NoteHelper(Context context) { 
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE NOTES (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, note TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int OldVersion, int NewVersion) {
    }

    public void insert (String note) {
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put("note", note);
        getWritableDatabase().insert("Notes", "note", cv);
    }

    public Cursor getAll() {
        return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT_id, note FROM notes", null));
    }

    public String getNote(Cursor c) {
        return(c.getString(1));
    }
}
```

and I suspect that the problem is in the manifest. here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="database.fli.one"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:name=".DatabaseFinalActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you for your opinions and advice in advance!

Comment: If I were you, I would try inserting more Log calls, so that you can be sure all methods you wrote are called properly. Is the DB file (note.db) created correctly? Does it contain "notes" table with two fields? Your manifest file, at a first look, seems OK

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple, change this:

```
getWritableDatabase().insert("Notes", "note", cv);
```

To this:

```
getWritableDatabase().insert("Notes", null, cv);
```

The middle parameter of [SQLiteDatabase.insert()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) is a workaround to insert a null / empty row into your database, by passing the the column `note` you told the database that this column would be null *regardless* of what is in the ContentValues.

In short, you told the database to enter a blank row. Use null instead.